# Multiple wireless routers and connected disc drive

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, wireless-access-point, repeater

I have a wireless ADSL router that came from my ISP installed, and it's working fine. However, there are two small issues that I would like to get resolved, and I hope that my *D-Link DIR-655* router that I also have at home can help me with them:

1) I have an external disc that I would like to access from other machines over the internet, and the *D-Link DIR-655* has a usb port that can be used for mass storage devices.

2) Some parts of the house that is furthest away from the ASDL router have pretty bad signals.

So what I would like to do is to install the *D-Link DIR-655* somewhere in my house to work as some sort of repeater/access point (what is the difference between those two terms?) so that I get good signal strength in my entire house, and in addition use the HDD connected to the *D-Link DIR-655* from any machine on the network.

Is this possible, and if it is, how can I configure the *D-Link DIR-655* to work the way I want it to?

Comment: It is only possible if either both routers support WDS or you can run an Ethernet cable (or power line Ethernet or the like) between the two routers. Other solutions will never quite work correctly.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - Thanks for commenting. If I am able to place them so that I can draw a cable between them, how should I set up the routers in that case?

Comment: Same SSID and encryption settings, different channels. In the router that's not connected to the WAN, disable the DHCP server and don't use its Internet/WAN port for anything. Connect a LAN port on one to a LAN port on the other.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - That worked as a charm. If you would care to change your comment(s) into an answer I'll be happy to mark it as accepted and upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect the two routers with an Ethernet cable.

Set them to the same SSID (wireless network name) and encryption settings. Use different channels if possible. In the router that's not connected to the WAN (Internet), disable the DHCP server and don't use its Internet/WAN port for anything. Connect a LAN port on one router to a LAN port on the other.

Answer (score 0):

You can install DD-WRT on your router, and then use it as repeater:

http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Repeater_Bridge